UBUNTU OS Hangs while taking xtrabackup in mysql 5.6 (ubuntu 14)
I have an 8TB percona mysql 5.6 database running in ubuntu 14 (quite obsolete) i know.
I have taking an xtrabackup during off peak hours that hangs the server with this error in the syslog
Oct 26 00:30:01 CRON[27589]: (root) CMD (/logs/db-backup/backup_script.sh)
Oct 26 03:30:58 kernel: [15616808.520083] task: ffff881f9205c800 ti: ffff881f9206a000 task.ti: ffff881f9206a000
Oct 26 03:30:58 kernel: [15616808.520151] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa001dc28>]  [<ffffffffa001dc28>] vmxnet3_xmit_frame+0x7d8/0xc80 [vmxnet3]
Oct 26 03:30:58 kernel: [15616808.520152] RSP: 0018:ffff881fbf2a3b00  EFLAGS: 00000286
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617288.619231] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 224s! [xtrabackup:27682]
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617288.619258] Modules linked in: iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nfsv3 nfsv4 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock autofs4 joydev hid_generic ppdev vmw_balloon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper usbhid cryptd vmwgfx hid serio_raw ttm drm i2c_piix4 shpchp vmw_vmci parport_pc mac_hid nfsd auth_rpcgss lp nfs_acl parport nfs lockd sunrpc fscache xfs libcrc32c psmouse vmw_pvscsi pata_acpi vmxnet3 floppy
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617288.619261] CPU: 8 PID: 27682 Comm: xtrabackup Tainted: G        W     3.13.0-65-generic #106-Ubuntu
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617310.999086] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 21s! [ksoftirqd/3:87]
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617310.999322] Modules linked in: iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nfsv3 nfsv4 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock autofs4 joydev hid_generic ppdev vmw_balloon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper usbhid cryptd vmwgfx hid serio_raw ttm drm i2c_piix4 shpchp vmw_vmci parport_pc mac_hid nfsd auth_rpcgss lp nfs_acl parport nfs lockd sunrpc fscache xfs libcrc32c psmouse vmw_pvscsi pata_acpi vmxnet3 floppy
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617310.999351] CPU: 3 PID: 87 Comm: ksoftirqd/3 Tainted: G        W     3.13.0-65-generic #106-Ubuntu
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781198] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#11 stuck for 21s! [ksoftirqd/11:24164]
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781496] Modules linked in: iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nfsv3 nfsv4 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock autofs4 joydev hid_generic ppdev vmw_balloon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper usbhid cryptd vmwgfx hid serio_raw ttm drm i2c_piix4 shpchp vmw_vmci parport_pc mac_hid nfsd auth_rpcgss lp nfs_acl parport nfs lockd sunrpc fscache xfs libcrc32c psmouse vmw_pvscsi pata_acpi vmxnet3 floppy
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781525] CPU: 11 PID: 24164 Comm: ksoftirqd/11 Tainted: G        W     3.13.0-65-generic #106-Ubuntu
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781527] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 12/12/2018
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781529] task: ffff88005d4ac800 ti: ffff8817717fc000 task.ti: ffff8817717fc000
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781530] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8172bf62>]  [<ffffffff8172bf62>] _raw_spin_lock+0x32/0x50
Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617313.781537] RSP: 0018:ffff8817717fdb48  EFLAGS: 00000206
Line 1813: Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617366.694005]  [<ffffffffa001c98b>] vmxnet3_rq_rx_complete+0x54b/0x810 [vmxnet3]
Line 1814: Oct 26 03:43:03 kernel: [15617366.694008]  [<ffffffffa001d0da>] vmxnet3_poll_rx_only+0x3a/0xb0 [vmxnet3]
see result of lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             12
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2294.609
BogoMIPS:              4589.21
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              33792K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11

